# Way to use synergy without X server running?

Tags: linux, arduino, xorg

I'm currently using synergy to switch between my arch system and OSX, but I do want to use it to switch to OSX without X server running, in bare tty. Is this possible anyhow? And yes, I red the docs that says you need to run X server in order to use synergy, but may be there's some alternative to it? Or maybe there's some open source hardware solutions to this (maybe based on arduino)?

Thanks, and sorry for off-topic if it had place.

Answer (score 4):

Synergy is great, but i think that it works **only** inside X.

There is however cool tty concept in [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/67659/linux-share-keyboard-over-network) 6 years old superuser answer.

if you are a sudo user on both machines, and configured ssh without password, you can try if this works for you:

```
sudo cat /dev/input/by-path/yourKeyboardOfComp1-deviceName | \
ssh user@remoteip 'sudo cat > /dev/input/by-path/keyboardOfComp2'
```

which should transfer keyboard to remote, without touching other comp, and perform 50% of synergy greatenest with just 2 common tools cat/ssh.
(works ok for my linux test, i do not know is there a diferences in osx)

First problem here is that cat will not lock device exclusive, and keyboard will send keystrokes to both comps... and second problem is that it will need time to make and configure some usefull scripts arround it.

So there is small project on github called [routekeys](http://github.com/asainnp/routekeys) that works ok for my needs (both keyboard&mouse for both console&x-server).

Not sure if there is other Synergy replacement for TTY and world without graphics... except similar small-projects mentioned for raspberry-pi [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/forward-mouse-and-keyboard-input-to-x-session).